# Create a new dataframe (with different schema) from selected information from another dataframe

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, scalability

I have a dataframe where the tag column contains different `key->values.` I try to filter out the `values` information where the `key=name`. The filtered out information should be put in a new dataframe.

The initial `df` has the following schema:

```
root
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |-- tags: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
 |-- nds: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- ref: long (nullable = true)
 |-- members: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- ref: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- role: string (nullable = true)
 |-- visible: boolean (nullable = true)
```

And I want a `newdf` of schema:

```
root
 |-- place: string (nullable = true)
 |-- num_evacuees string (nullable = true)
```

How should I do the filter? I tried a lot of methods, where I tried to have a normal filter at least. But everytime, the result of the filter is an empty dataframe each time. For example:

```
val newdf = df.filter($"tags"("key") contains "name")
val newdf = df.where(places("tags")("key") === "name")
```

I tried a lot more methods, but none of it has worked
How should I do the proper filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the result you want with:

```scala
         val df = Seq(
                 (1L, Map("sf" -> "100")),
                 (2L, Map("ny" -> "200"))
               ).toDF("id", "tags")
               
               val resultDf = df
                 .select(explode(map_filter(col("tags"), (k, _) => k === "ny")))
                 .withColumnRenamed("key", "place")
                 .withColumnRenamed("value", "num_evacuees")
               
               resultDf.printSchema
               resultDf.show
```

Which will show:

```
root
 |-- place: string (nullable = false)
 |-- num_evacuees: string (nullable = true)

+-----+------------+
|place|num_evacuees|
+-----+------------+
|   ny|         200|
+-----+------------+
```

The key idea is to use `map_filter` to select the fields from the map you want then `explode` turns the map into two columns (`key` and `value`) which you can then rename to make the `DataFrame` match your specification.

The above example assumes you want to get a single value to demonstrate the idea. The lambda function used by `map_filter` can be as complex as necessary. Its signature `map_filter(expr: Column, f: (Column, Column) => Column): Column` shows that as long as you return a `Column` it will be happy.

If you wanted to filter a large number of entries you could do something like:

```
val resultDf = df
  .withColumn("filterList", array("sf", "place_n"))
  .select(explode(map_filter(col("tags"), (k, _) => array_contains(col("filterList"), k))))
```

Comment: The thing is that I want to obtain the value from to specific keys between 100 different keys. I need the value of all key=name and the value of the related key=population.

Comment: @EnesK, I've updated the answer with a more complete example which I think is closer to what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to extract the keys of the map column (tags), then use array_contains to check for a key called "name".

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val newdf = df.filter(array_contains(map_keys($"tags), "name"))
```